# How to get the complete id of an element by knowing the partial id in karate?

Tags: iframe, karate

In my application, there is a Credit Card field which is in iframe and the id of it is dynamic.
The constant id is 'flex-microform-' and anything after that is dynamic.

Can someone help to fetch the complete id using Karate?

Comment: read the docs please: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#locateall-with-filter